# squaring a number using bitwise multiplication or using *

Tags: algorithm, c

I had written a code which is given in the following **code 1**,**code1** & **Driver program** section of the post.

I have to ask which of the following code is more efficient and takes less time to execute on the **C(GCC 4.9.2)** compiler.

I had a little confusion in the following code which is multiplication of `input1 *input1` which  I might think will takes lot more time so
**Is there any way to optimize like using bitwise multiplication.**

## Code 1

```
int FindingMoves(int input1)
    {
        if(input1>0)
        {
               ++input1;
               input1 <<=1;
               ++input1;
               return input1*input1;

        }
        if(input1 == 0){return 8;}
       
    }
```

This is the first code which I had written using bitwise multiplication but fails to write a code to multiply two numbers(input1*input1).

## Code 2

```
int FindingMoves(int input1)
    {
        if(input1>0)
        {
              
               return (2*(input1+1)+1)*(2*(input1+1)+1);

        }
        if(input1 == 0){return 8;}
       
    }
```

This is straight forward code which is a simpler version of above.

## DriverProgram

```
int main() {
    int output = 0;
    int ip1;
    scanf("%d", &ip1);
    output = FindingMoves(ip1);
    printf("%d\n", output);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the driver program to above code snippets.

Help me here to write optimized and efficient code. Any mysteries will be welcome regarding macro or something.

Comment: "following code 1,code1 & Driver program"  Did you mean "following Code 1 , Code 2 & Driver program"  (1--> 2)?

Comment: Code 1 and Code 2 are broken, missing return value when `input < 0`.

Comment: Both approaches **square** a number using `*`.  Title does not match body goals.

Answer (score 1):

#### Negative input causes undefined behavior

If `input1` is negative, your code reaches the end of function without returning a value.  Either you should return something such as 0 in that case, or you should make the input type be `unsigned`.

#### Simplification using math

Your expression `(2*(input1+1)+1)` evaluates to `2*input1+3`.  So to minimize the work done, you could do:

```
if (input1 > 0) {
    input1 += input1 + 3;
    return input1 * input1;
}
```

This has two adds, one multiply, and zero shifts.  This is one less shift than the code in "code1" and one less multiply than the code in "code2", so it should be faster than either of them.